# An algorithm which efficiently generates random samples without replacement, from a large range [0-N], N ~ 10^12?

Tags: randomized-algorithms, random-number-generator

I want an algorithm which generates random integers, without replacement, from a large range [0-N], N~10^12.

However, the whole range should not be stored in memory. The memory footprint should be O(1) relative to N. The algorithm can (probably must) retain state after every sample request.

The randomness should be "strong" in the cryptographic sense.

Comment: Use a block cipher. Specifically, [Format-preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption).

Comment: A powerful random engine that generates a random number from [1, (N+1)!] will solve this problem trivially. So is there any limit on the random engine being used?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.8. What's your suggestion?

Comment: What’s “O(1) relative to N”?

Comment: Basically means constant. You can do a web search for "big o notation".

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Wikipedia states that FPE is equivalent to a random permutation of {1,...,N}, but I cannot find this to be proved anywhere. I have also tested this with libffx (via pyffx), and it doesn't seem to produce permutations (i.e. eventually a number previously seen will reappear, before all numbers are exhausted).

Comment: A format-preserving encryption function is an invertible mapping from $\{1,\ldots,N\}$ to $\{1,\ldots,N\}$, also known as a permutation. In order to generate $m$ random integers without replacement, choose a random key, and apply your FPE to $1,\ldots,m$. Unfortunately I have never heard of `libffx`, so can't help you with that.